# Why do I get AutoSave Clipping.txt files auto generates on my desktop screen

Tags: macos, catalina, autosave

I don't know how but I get to see a lot of auto clipping files being generated on my desktop screen.
This is how my desktop looks
[image]

Comment: It's very likely to be caused by some third-party software. Can you think of any software that might be doing Autosaves? Do the contents of these text files provide any clue?

Comment: Yeah correct, it was a tool named Flycut which is a clipboard manager.